# Insert HTML directly in PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have WPF application in which user enters some text in rich text box(rtb), I convert that rtb string to HTML and then convert that HTML to image and then insert it in the PDF document

```
using (Stream inputPdfStream = new FileStream("sample.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (Stream outputPdfStream = new FileStream("result2.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
  var reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);
  var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);

  PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = null;

  int c = reader.NumberOfPages;
  iTextSharp.text.Image image =   TextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ConvertXamltohtmltoImage(xamlstring));

  foreach (var item in lst)
  {
      image.ScaleToFit(item._Size.Width, item._Size.Height);
      image.SetAbsolutePosition(item.Location.X, item.Location.Y);
      pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(item.pageNo);
      pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
  }
  stamper.Close();
}
```

My question is can I insert HTML directly into PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra DLL to do that: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/
See the demo: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/
Unfortunately, the documentation hasn't been updated recently. We're working on it.

Comment: iTextSharp support for html is rather poor. You might not be able to process all html tags

Comment: it has the same license tat apply to itextsharp because i am using version 4.1.6?

Comment: No, please read http://lowagie.com/iText2 and http://lowagie.com/FOSSHygiene and http://lowagie.com/bumodels

Comment: that changed my thought of everything must be opensource