# Creating PDF with styles and colors as in html

Tags: asp.net, css, pdf

In web application project I am dynamically creating a PDF file, for this we are using third party tools like itextsharp , Winnovative etc and its working fine but in the PDF files the styles and colors are not reflecting and I want to create the PDF just as a XEROX copy of web page. Is there any third party components which will create PDF files just as the html..?

Comment: How styles and colors are not reflecting? Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean adding HTML directly into PDF, this can be implemented using iTextSharp.
[Insert HTML directly in PDF using itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529244/insert-html-directly-in-pdf-using-itextsharp)

iTextSharp also can be used to add colors, fonts, shapes, graphics ...
that series of articles explain that in details
[Create PDFs in ASP.NET - getting started with iTextSharp](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/80/Create-PDFs-in-ASP.NET-getting-started-with-iTextSharp)